# Can I ask this type of question? I don't know whether it can be qualified as research level?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question on Math.Stackexchange, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911783/is-my-proof-wrong), can I ask here. I have done little research on proving for the general case of n-variables other than mentioned in my answer.

Comment: One small problem is that the notation 'cyc' of the question is unexplained. (Don't bother explaining; I already clicked further back and found out.) But no, I think the level of this question would probably be considered too low for MO. "Research level" may be taken to refer to research of professional mathematicians and PhD candidates.

Comment: Also, questions of the form 'please check my proof' are usually frowned upon.